# Finding full phrase in list before a success flag

Tags: python, python-3.x

code:

```
# function - send a get request to each url
def send_get_request(link, search_for):
    try:
        html = send_request = requests.get(link)
        for i in search_for:
            if any(i in html.text for i in search_for):
                return link
            else:
                return False
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: " + str(e))

# search for any of these items
search_for = ['about me', 'home page']
```

When looking in my **search_for** list items, if it finds the word **about** it flags it as a success. I need the full word to be found which would be **about me** the same with **home** and **home page**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall`

```
import re

search_for = ['about me', 'home page', 'home']

def send_get_request(link, search_for):
   try:
       html = requests.get(link)
   except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
       print("Error: {}".format(e))

   if re.findall('|'.join(search_for), html.text):
       return html.text
   else:
       return False
```

Comment: I think it is still flagging just the 1 word, in this example which it shows as a success: https://www.gta-multiplayer.cz/cz/profile/idawn/ in the html code there is only this: <p class="About">Its not what you think</p> when it should be looking for **about me** the 2 words, am i right in saying that? thank you for the help Jab, appreciated.

Comment: You're probably going to have more luck with beautifulsoap if that's what you're trying to do. What I did above searches for the words in that list. in the text provided ignoring any html markdown.

Comment: Hi Jab, from what i can see it stops after the first word like: **about me** after it finds **about** it stops looking at the rest of the string, i'm not sure why it's doing this i'll need to look in to this more it seems, thank you!